Adding a Vanity Light
I am adding a vanity light. I open up the cover plate to the existing light, and find it is on the same circuit as the hall (3-way) and the bedroom overhead light. I find 120V from the white wire to ground. 120V white to black. zero from black to ground. I am assuming the white is reversed somewhere. The white and black are stabbed into the switch. can i use the terminal lugs to add the vanity light simply black to same black, white to same white, and ground pigtailed to ground?

If white and black is on the switch, you have an older switch loop.
The white wire is used as a hot and the black is switch hot.  The white is supposed to be marked black or red at both ends to say it is not neutral.
You should have a white wire connected to a black/s wire/s at the light, and a extra white/s connected to the white from the light/s
So right in thinking black to black, but must find the white wire/s used for neutral.
